# Can a additive identity itself contain any vector considering it should be unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

Hi Iam studying Linear Algebra's vector space.

Question : Let $V$ be the vector of all real numbers with operations $u + v  = uv - 1 $  and $c * v = v$ where c is a constant and u and v are vectors form a vector space?

I know that this doesn't form a vector space because of associativity but i'm curious about it's additive identity

Now I have found the additive identity as $(1+1/u)$

But This doesn't make the identity unique.
Does that mean it's wrong?

Comment: Have you checked whether the defined addition is associative?

Comment: @drhab yeaps I know that it doesn't form vector space but I still want to know the case of such an additive identity or it's possibility just in case!

Comment: You presented it as a vector space while it is not. That is confusing of course. You should edit your question in order to take away that confusion.

Comment: @drhab apologies for that I amended the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a vector space. Because your addition is **not associative**!

I'll rewrite $u\oplus v=uv-1, c\odot v=v$ to reduce confusion.

$(u\oplus v)\oplus w=(uv-1)\oplus w=(uv-1)w-1=uvw-w-1$, and $u\oplus (v\oplus w)=u\oplus (vw-1)=u(vw-1)-1=uvw-u-1$. They are not same in general! Especially, $1\oplus(0\oplus-1)\ne(1\oplus 0)\oplus -1$.

Also, when $e$ is identity of (V,$\oplus$), then $0\oplus e=0$ must hold. But $0\oplus e=0e-1\ne 0$. So, there are no $\oplus$-identity.

Comment: Oh yeah I know it's not the vector space I just want to know if such a identity is possible or not?

Comment: @huzaifaimran I edited. Please see my last part.

Comment: Understood completely Thanks!
Just to clarify a bit, here 0 is a scalar or a vector itself?

Comment: @huzaifaimran 0 in here is vector.

Answer (score 1):

Most people are pointing out that the operation is not associative, and they're correct, but you asked about the identity:

In the axioms for a vector space the identity axiom is the following:

> There exists an element $0 \in V$ such that $v + 0 = v$ for all $v \in V$.

The important point here is that there is *one* element $0$ that works with *every* element $v$.

If you have an operation defined by $(u, v) \mapsto uv - 1$ then you've noticed that for any $u$ the element $v = 1 + \frac{1}{u}$ satisfies $(u, 1 + \frac{1}{u}) \mapsto u$.  So, for example $(1, 2) \mapsto 1$.  But $2$ is not the identity because if I swap $1$ for a different number, say $(3, 2) \mapsto 5$ I don't get $3$.

So the answer to your question is no, you cannot have a different identity element for each vector.  The identity must be unique, meaning you must have a single element that functions as the identity for **all** vectors.